# 404 Error when trying to find view file

Tags: php, model-view-controller, kohana

I've started learning Kohana to learn more about MVC Frameworks. I'm having a problem trying to access one of my views despite it working fine for another view in the same directory.

The one that works is this:

```
 public function action_index()
   {
     $this->template->content = View::factory('pages/index');
   }
```

So going to / on my server takes me to the `index.php` file.

The one that doesn't work is this:

```
 public function action_edit_account()
   {
     $this->template->content = View::factory('pages/edit_account');
   }
```

If I go to `/edit_account` it takes me to a 404 page despite there being a file called `edit_account.php` in my `/views/pages/` directory.

I've probably made a pretty stupid mistake but Kohana doesn't have the best documentation so any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: According to [the docs](https://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/mvc/views) this implementation looks correct. Out of curiosity, does it work if you instead try to access it from `edit-account` with a dash instead of underscore? Or if you rename the file to `editaccount.php` with no separating character? It's possible the framework is converting it to something else you're not expecting.

Comment: I've tried removing the separating character from the file name and then updating the controller to reflect this change but it still seems to 404.

Comment: 404 you took, when action dont exists. When view not exists you took 500.

Comment: Kohana native don't translate `edit-account` to `action_edit_account`. You must use `edit_account` action.